# Adjusting grid lines and plotting significance stars in GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having some trouble getting the grid lines in the right place in GGplot2. What I would like is for there to be a horizontal red grid line between each label on the y axis in the below plot so that grid lines are above & below the plotted points for each variable (i.e. clearly see which variable is associated with which points). Usually I would achieve this with `panel.grid.minor.y` but doesnt seem to work for me here.

I would also like coloured significance stars to be plotted next to each plotted point based upon the p values in the dataset (i.e. '*' for <0.05 & '**' for <0.01).

Code below.

```
    library(ggplot2)

data = read.csv("data.csv")

data = data %>% mutate(ymin = estimate - std.error,
                           ymax = estimate + std.error)

ggplot(data, aes(x = term, y = estimate)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "#000000", size = 0.75) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, group = rev(model), color = model, shape = model), 
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.55), size = 2.5, fatten = 1.25,
                  show.legend = T) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,16,17,18)) +
  labs(x="Variable", y="Standardized Estimate") + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="right",
        legend.key.height = unit(1.5, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.title = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = 2,
                                          size = 0.25,
                                          linetype = 2)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

[image]

Ive included some example data:

| term | estimate | n.eff | std.error | statistic | p.value | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Topo | 0.060916487 | 12446.96876 | 0.013508901 | 4.509359077 | 6.50E-06 | A |
| Den | 0.035555534 | 12446.96876 | 0.010579943 | 3.360654531 | 0.00077758 | A |
| LF | 0.158012737 | 12446.96876 | 0.012220115 | 12.93054377 | 3.03E-38 | A |
| Depth | 0.00710977 | 12446.96876 | 0.010945531 | 0.649559188 | 0.515977002 | A |
| Rad | 0.125195466 | 12446.96876 | 0.011414807 | 10.9678123 | 5.46E-28 | A |
| TWI | 0.005096983 | 12446.96876 | 0.011282293 | 0.451768399 | 0.651435838 | A |
| Clay | 0.041957768 | 12446.96876 | 0.01277691 | 3.283874355 | 0.001023906 | A |
| Sand | -0.010639431 | 12446.96876 | 0.012136726 | -0.876631118 | 0.380687031 | A |
| pH | -0.074423302 | 12446.96876 | 0.010705113 | -6.952126623 | 3.60E-12 | A |
| C | -0.045310227 | 12446.96876 | 0.012775308 | -3.546703193 | 0.000390084 | A |
| Open | -0.102878008 | 12446.96876 | 0.016137241 | -6.37519186 | 1.83E-10 | A |
| Topo | 0.180920253 | 11899.91683 | 0.013318732 | 13.5838946 | 4.99E-42 | B |
| Den | 0.060802645 | 11899.91683 | 0.010431006 | 5.829029832 | 5.58E-09 | B |
| LF | 0.116342392 | 11899.91683 | 0.012048089 | 9.656501823 | 4.61E-22 | B |
| Depth | 0.00753326 | 11899.91683 | 0.010791447 | 0.698076925 | 0.485129088 | B |
| Rad | -0.122732543 | 11899.91683 | 0.011254118 | -10.90556787 | 1.08E-27 | B |
| TWI | -0.117228356 | 11899.91683 | 0.011123468 | -10.53883138 | 5.72E-26 | B |
| Clay | 0.01079656 | 11899.91683 | 0.012597046 | 0.85707084 | 0.391405736 | B |
| Sand | 0.017787267 | 11899.91683 | 0.011965873 | 1.486499723 | 0.13714699 | B |
| pH | 0.003459146 | 11899.91683 | 0.010554414 | 0.327743981 | 0.743105246 | B |
| C | 0.196000084 | 11899.91683 | 0.012595466 | 15.56116142 | 1.34E-54 | B |
| Open | -0.150403434 | 11899.91683 | 0.015910072 | -9.4533472 | 3.28E-21 | B |

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A discrete scale has no minor breaks. Hence, `panel.grid.minor` will have no effect. But you could easily fake minor grid lines  using `geom_h/vline`. For your siginifance stars you could use a `geom_text`.

Note: I dropped the `coord_flip` and switched the role of `x` and `y`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data <- data |>
  mutate(
    xmin = estimate - std.error,
    xmax = estimate + std.error,
    label = case_when(
      p.value < .01 ~ "**",
      p.value < .05 ~ "*",
      .default = ""
    )
  )

data_grid <- data |>
  distinct(term) |>
  mutate(
    term_num = as.numeric(factor(term)) - .5
  ) |>
  # Drop first
  filter(!term_num %in% range(term_num)[1])

ggplot(data, aes(x = estimate, y = term)) +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "#000000", size = 0.75) +
  geom_hline(
    data = data_grid,
    aes(yintercept = term_num),
    color = "red",
    linewidth = .25
  ) +
  geom_pointrange(
    aes(
      xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
      group = rev(model),
      color = model, shape = model
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.55),
    size = 2.5, fatten = 1.25,
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label,
      x = xmax + .005,
      group = rev(model),
      color = model
    ),
    hjust = 0,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.55),
    vjust = .75
    ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 17, 18)) +
  labs(y = "Variable", x = "Standardized Estimate") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "right",
    legend.key.height = unit(1.5, "cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  term = c(
    "Topo", "Den", "LF", "Depth",
    "Rad", "TWI", "Clay", "Sand", "pH", "C", "Open", "Topo",
    "Den", "LF", "Depth", "Rad", "TWI", "Clay", "Sand", "pH",
    "C", "Open"
  ),
  estimate = c(
    0.060916487, 0.035555534,
    0.158012737, 0.00710977, 0.125195466, 0.005096983, 0.041957768,
    -0.010639431, -0.074423302, -0.045310227, -0.102878008,
    0.180920253, 0.060802645, 0.116342392, 0.00753326,
    -0.122732543, -0.117228356, 0.01079656, 0.017787267,
    0.003459146, 0.196000084, -0.150403434
  ),
  n.eff = c(
    12446.96876, 12446.96876,
    12446.96876, 12446.96876, 12446.96876, 12446.96876,
    12446.96876, 12446.96876, 12446.96876, 12446.96876, 12446.96876,
    11899.91683, 11899.91683, 11899.91683, 11899.91683,
    11899.91683, 11899.91683, 11899.91683, 11899.91683, 11899.91683,
    11899.91683, 11899.91683
  ),
  std.error = c(
    0.013508901, 0.010579943,
    0.012220115, 0.010945531, 0.011414807, 0.011282293, 0.01277691,
    0.012136726, 0.010705113, 0.012775308, 0.016137241,
    0.013318732, 0.010431006, 0.012048089, 0.010791447,
    0.011254118, 0.011123468, 0.012597046, 0.011965873, 0.010554414,
    0.012595466, 0.015910072
  ),
  statistic = c(
    4.509359077, 3.360654531,
    12.93054377, 0.649559188, 10.9678123, 0.451768399, 3.283874355,
    -0.876631118, -6.952126623, -3.546703193, -6.37519186,
    13.5838946, 5.829029832, 9.656501823, 0.698076925,
    -10.90556787, -10.53883138, 0.85707084, 1.486499723,
    0.327743981, 15.56116142, -9.4533472
  ),
  p.value = c(
    6.5e-06, 0.00077758, 3.03e-38,
    0.515977002, 5.46e-28, 0.651435838, 0.001023906,
    0.380687031, 3.6e-12, 0.000390084, 1.83e-10, 4.99e-42, 5.58e-09,
    4.61e-22, 0.485129088, 1.08e-27, 5.72e-26, 0.391405736,
    0.13714699, 0.743105246, 1.34e-54, 3.28e-21
  ),
  model = c(
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
    "B", "B", "B", "B"
  )
)
```